# Struggling when creating and updating Work Items using Azure Devops Node Api

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

So, I'm creating a project using Node.Js and the azure devops node api. I'm being able to work with it, connect, get Work Items using WIQL, and update those Work Items.

I understand that in order to Create or Update I must declare a Json Document with the operation I want to do, for example.

```
[
  {
    op: 'add',
    path: '/fields/System.Title',
    value: 'Created From Api',
  },
  {
    op: 'add',
    path: '/fields/System.Description',
    value: "PBI Created from Api",
  },
  {
    op: 'add',
    path: '/relations/-',
    value: {
       rel: 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse',
       url: WorkItemFather.url
    }
  }
]
```

The thing is, where do I get documentation for this Json?
I copy and pasted those operations from the web, but for example, did not found how to add a Father to a Work Item, neither why it's done like that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#jsonpatchdocument

Is the best link I got.

How ss the path related to the Work Item I want to interact with?
Is it like if it was an object, and instead of going `WorkItem.fields["System.Title"]` its replacement in the Json is path: `'/fields/System.Title'` ?

I'm kinda lost with it.